# Change text on click script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding one audio player which play/pause on button but its also autoplaying. So first button that appears is Pause button and when its clicked it pauses the audio and changes to Play button. Now I tried to add text under it that says Playing or Paused. I managed to do that but its only happening when the button is clicked. So when I refresh the website there is no text under playing audio, then I have to click it and it will appear first Paused and then after one more hit Playing.

So I want Playing to be under Pause Button without needing to click it.

```js
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('player');
  if (image.src.match("pause")) {
    image.src = "assets/img/icons/play.png";
    document.getElementById("fetch").innerHTML = "Paused";
  } else {
    image.src = "assets/img/icons/pause.png";
    document.getElementById("fetch").innerHTML = "Playing";
  }
}
var playing = true;

function action() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  if (playing === false) {
    audio.play();
    playing = true;
    document.getElementById("append").innerHTML = "Playing";
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    playing = false;
  }
}
```

```css
#audioplayer {
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
  bottom: 11px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 81px;
  width: 81px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #0FB6D1;
}

#audioplayer:hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #6854e7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #6854e7;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #6854e7;
}

#fetch {
  font-family: 'gothic';
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 1.9px;
}
```

```html
<div id="audioplayer">

  <img id="player" onclick="action();changeImage();" src="assets/img/icons/pause.png" />

  <audio id="audio" src="assets/music/music.wav" loop autoloop autoplay></audio>

  <p id="fetch"></p>
  <p id="append"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Why not add 'Playing' to the html by default, then it will be there on page load.

Comment: Well I can but it wont dissapear and change again when button is clicked

Comment: There is nothing to do with CSS.You better consider removing styles and tag from the question body so that the actual problem will have more focus.

Comment: @Regrets your innerHTML line will change it on click. Just add it to your `else` as well  `innerHTML = ""`

Comment: I have added but its not showing when the page loads, it has to be clicked to show, I want to show by deafult when page loads Playing

Comment: Does anyone knows answer?

Comment: @user500665 can you help me and write a working code in answer?

Comment: please someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you have "fetch" & "append" divs so I have removed one for this example.

```
document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click', function() {
  action();
});

var playing = true;
var image = document.getElementById('player');
function action() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  if (playing === false) {
    audio.play();
    playing = true;
    document.getElementById("fetch").innerHTML = "Playing";
    image.src = "assets/img/icons/pause.png";
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    playing = false;
    document.getElementById("fetch").innerHTML = "Paused";
    image.src = "assets/img/icons/play.png";
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="audioplayer">

  <img id="player" src="assets/img/icons/pause.png" />

  <audio id="audio" src="assets/music/music.wav" loop autoloop autoplay></audio>

  <p id="fetch">Playing</p>

</div>
```

Comment: hey man its not working properely, I just noticed, when clicked it doesnt switch to play button I have to click twice

Comment: @Regrets I just got the play and pause pngs around the wrong way. Edited answer.